# Config block in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm a newbie in Magento. I have a question. I config following the guide on this website

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="magentotutorial/helloworld/simple_page.phtml" />
</default>
</layout>
```

But it doesn't work. But  I fix `<default>` to `<helloworld_index_index>`, it run.
I don't understand this issue. What is the diffrent?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [magento.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<default>` and `<helloworld_index_index>` are known as "Layout Handles".

If you study `page.xml` file in a layout folder of your theme or default theme, you will find that `<default>` layout handle has already been assigned with a "Block element" of name `root`. So, defining the `root` Block element again in the same layout handle doesn't make any sense to magento.

If you want to use a same Block element in the same layout handle then you should **refer** it using the Block element type `<reference>` as shown below:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <!-- Your changes here -->
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Anyway, coming to the point, `<helloworld_index_index>` layout handle worked for you because it doesn't have a block element `root` already assigned somewhere else in layout xml files.